# FATAL: GTM error, could not obtain snapshot. Current XID = 0, Autovac = 0

Tags: postgresql, postgres-xl

After running virtually any command (e.g. createdb test) from GTM host inside pgxc_ctl tool, I am getting the following error:

```
FATAL:  GTM error, could not obtain snapshot. Current XID = 0, Autovac = 0
```

PostgresXL is [configured](http://files.postgres-xl.org/documentation/tutorial-createcluster.html) and installed on 4 nodes (/etc/hosts):

```
172.23.102.115 coordinator001
172.23.102.116 datanode001
172.23.103.0 datanode002
172.23.102.114 gtm001
```

So that each can *ssh* into another one and pg_hba.conf contains:

```
host    all             all             0.0.0.0/0               trust
```

GTM node has this [configuration](https://gist.github.com/ewiger/a71689db37fec5c93a9920621f52b2cf)

Would appreciate any tips or ideas where to dig next.

**[edit]**

Getting this error during the direct connection:

```
psql -h coordinator001 -p 6668 -U postgres testdb
psql: FATAL:  GTM error, could not obtain snapshot. Current XID = 0, Autovac = 0
```

Comment: I get impression my config is a mess. Now trying a correct one from here http://deepdive.stanford.edu/using-pgxl

Comment: checking firewall and following the above scenario seems to work. Once pgxc_ctl exports configs to the remote nodes, it helps a lot to check them

Comment: Network seems to be the most plausible cause. Happened during the network fluctuation.